# How many spellpoints would a duskblade have under the Spell Points variant rule?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

I am in the middle of helping a player create a Duskblade. I have been using a small variant on the Spell Point system found in Unearthed Arcana (the point amounts are the same, though). I was wondering how different non-SRD classes fit into this system, and specifically the Duskblade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no official guidelines for this.

However, the formula was discovered on the old WotC boards, and [the information has survived to this day](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?p=15256702).

The one who did the preservation ran the numbers for the Duskblade, and came up with the following progression:

```
Level   SP
1       2
2       3
3       4
4       5
5       11
6       15
7       21
8       25
9       35
10      44
11      54
12      62
13      77
14      89
15      103
16      118
17      137
18      153
19      179
20      200
```

Personally, I find that this conversion treats the Duskblade rather poorly, as one of the strength of the class is its very great number of low level slots, which have little weight in the conversion formula. I would come up with a formula that grants it more base spell points than even the Sorcerer, to retain its canonical advantage.