# How many spellpoints would a duskblade have under Ernir's Psionic mechanics, Arcane flavor variant rule?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, homebrew, psionics

I am in the middle of helping answer [a question about helping a player create a Duskblade](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/21923/how-many-spellpoints-would-a-duskblade-have-under-the-spell-points-variant-rule). I would be using [@Ernir’s Psionic mechanics, Arcane flavor variant](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?t=194002k). I was wondering how different unconverted classes fit into this system, and specifically the Duskblade.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My initial reaction is to give them "very many" spell points. The Vancian base class gets a very, very large number of their frequently used lower level spells per day, leading me to believe the class was intended to have durability enough to keep pace with mundane characters in most situations. Also, the class relies largely on augment-scaling blasting spells, further increasing its dependence on a large spell point pool.

So far, I have based my spell point progressions on simple quadratic equations, tweaked as experience and feedback has started streaming in.
My starting point would be to copy the Sorcerer progression. In [the related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/21923/how-many-spellpoints-would-a-duskblade-have-under-the-spell-points-variant-rule) I suggested giving it *more* than the Sorcerer, but that included compensation for how thoroughly the Unearthed Arcana spell point variant shafts the Sorcerer with respect to spell points. Should that not be sufficient, I would start experimenting with increasing the multiplier of the quadratic coefficient (I would not like giving the Duskblade significantly more spell points at the lower levels) to something like 1.2 (from 1). This modified equation would give something like:

```
lvl    Sor     Dusk?
1      3       3
2      7       7
3      13      14
4      21      24
5      31      36
6      43      50
7      57      66
8      73      85
9      91      107
10     111     131
11     133     157
12     157     185
13     183     216
14     211     250
15     241     286
16     273     324
17     307     364
18     343     407
19     381     453
20     421     501
```

But again, my initial feeling is to copy the Sorcerer progression.